# Disable Hyperlinks in Pricebook

Tags: apex, visualforce, pricebook

How would I disable the hyperlinks for the product name in a priceboook? I want the user to still be able to mark checkboxes to select the product but a lot of them end up clicking the product name instead since intuitively a hyperlink is very tempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. At least, not without writing your own Visualforce pages. However, Salesforce does this *everywhere* in the UI whenever there is a lookup. This is more of a training issue than anything, because if they're clicking on links instead of checking boxes in one place, they're going to have problems using Salesforce as an application. Every detail page, list view, home page view, related list, report, etc., everywhere in the system behaves the same way 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way I could somehow manipulate permissions within the app so that users can't access those products via the pricebook page? I didn't think there was but I'm just curious

Comment: @Brohibition You could remove the Read permission for Products, but that wouldn't solve any particular usage problem. Either they wouldn't be able to see the product related fields, or they'd still be links that, when clicked on, would just direct them to a "insufficient privileges" page.

Comment: What about editing metadata? Could you either get rid of the hyperlink there or at least move the product name farther to the right in order for a user to not feel inclined to click it? (Because currently it has to be the first item since it is the name)

Comment: @Brohibition I've already taken a look into that. The page layout editor states that the list view isn't customizable. So, for now, you'll have to deal with it. I wish I had a better answer for you.